# Char pointer to char array

Tags: arrays, c++-cli

So I have this method that returns a char pointer:

```
Private: char* currentSelectedDevice()
         {
            String^ comboboxText = counterComboBox->Text;
            marshal_context ^ context = gcnew marshal_context();
            char* temp;
            cont char* convertedString = context->marshal_as<const char*>(comboboxText);
            temp = const_cast<char *>(convertedString);
            char* oneCounterPort = strtok (temp, " =");
            return oneCounterPort;
         }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to copy this method to a char array. I was thinking of using a for loop but that didn't work out as I wanted. So how can I do this?

I was thinking something like this might work:

```
char temp[sizeof(currentSelectedDevice())] = currentSelectedDevice();
```

Comment: Why are you even bothering with a `char *`? You should either keep using `System::String` or use `std::string`, or `CString`. Then you don't have to worry about memory allocation and copying of strings.

Comment: @crashmstr please, tell me than how I can convert a String^ to an char array.

Comment: No, because you really should not need to (or at least you don't show us how you are going to use this and *why* it must be a `char []`). You should be using `System::String^`, or if you need to interface with C++ code, `std::string str = marshal_as<std::string>(counterComboBox->Text);`.

Comment: I'll give more explanation. The syntax I'm using requires an array of chars, it won't allow me to use a pointer of chars, the next thing is I only need the charactes before the "=" this is very hard to do with a String^ so that's the main reason I converted it to a char pointer.

Comment: It is easy to do with `System::String^`, you can use `Split` as well as other ways - [System.String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String_methods(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Still I need the char array for the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Marshal::Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Your functoin would look like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // In case you use C (for malloc() access)

// C++/CLI function
char * currentSelectedDevice()
{
    String^ comboBoxText = counterComboBox->Text;

    // Allocate unmanaged memory:
    char *result = (char*)malloc(comboBoxText->Length);

    // Copy comboBoxText to result:
    Marshal::Copy( comboBoxText ->ToCharArray(), 0, IntPtr( (char*) result ), comboBoxText->Length );

    return result;
}
```

It copies the content of `comboBoxText` (**note** the call of `ToCharArray()` here) from location `0` to `comboBoxText.Length` into `result`.

The calling `C` function will then e.g. can use it like this:

```
// Calling C function
void read_combo_box_text()
{
  // Get text:
  char * cbxText = currentSelectedDevice();

  // .. Do something with it

  // Free (if don't needed anymore)
  free(cbxText);
}
```

Hope this helps.

**Note:** If you do this for `C++` don't include `stdlib.h` and replace `malloc()` by `new` and `free()` by `delete[]`.

Comment: Could you please give me an easyer example?

Comment: It says: none of the 16 overloads could convert al the argument types if I try to copy it.

Comment: @Thealon What exactly don't you understand? Did you read the documentation for `Marshal::Copy` and are you passing the right parameters?

Comment: I did read the documentation, I don't understand your code. As for passing the right parameters: im passing currentSelectedDevice() as first argument second argument is an array of chars (char temp[64]="";) the third argument is a 0 and the 4th argument is a 4. Also I could use this Marshal::Copy(IntPtr, array<Single>, Int32, Int32) I just don't know how.

Comment: You don't `free` when you `new`, it should be `delete [] cbxText;`

Comment: Its gives me a bounch of errors: comboboxText undeclared identifier, comboboxText undeclared identifier, left of ->ToCharArray must point to class/struct/union/generic type, left of .Length must have class/struct/union, strcpy: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char' to 'char*'.

Comment: @StefanR.Falk could you provide me a way to solve these please? I updated my code in my question.

Comment: @Thealon sorry made some typos. I wrote `comboBoxText` and `comboboxText` and is should be `comboBoxText->Length`. I edited the answer.